# Laravel 5.2: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

This is my first time using Laravel 5.2 and I am trying to view the list of two quotes with it's author

The data I want to list are;

1. *quotes* from table *quotes*
2. *name* from table *author*

My DB schema for *quotes* and *authors*

quotes;

```
Schema::create('quotes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('author_id');
    $table->text('quotes');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

authors;

```
Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('name');
    $table->text('origin');
    $table->integer('died');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My controller is like this;

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Quotes;
use App\Authors;

class QuotesController extends Controller {

public function index() {
    $quotes = Quotes::with('authors')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(25);
    return view('quotes.all',[
        'quotes' => $quotes
    ]);
}
```

My Authors model;

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Authors extends Model {
    public function Quotes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Quotes');
    }
}
```

My Quotes model;

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Quotes extends Model {
    public function Authors() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Authors');
    }
}
```

and lastly, my view of course;

```
<ul class="list-group">
    @forelse ($quotes as $quote)   
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $quote->quotes }} <br>
            <span class="label label-primary">{{ $quote->authors->name }}</span>
        </li>
    @empty
        <p>No quotes</p>
    @endforelse
</ul>
```

I am new to PHP and I hope you can help me with this matter. I am really appreciate.

Comment: Would help if you said which part of the code the error was coming from.

Comment: Just a note: models are usually named in singular as a naming convention

Comment: @apokryfos, when I remove {{ $quote->author->name }}, the program run.

Comment: Thank you very much @RasmusRosengren.

Comment: What about replacing `{{ $quote->authors->name }}` with `{{ $quote->Authors()->name }}`

Comment: Name the relation methods with a small letter. On the 'Quote' model method 'author()', on the 'Author' model method 'quotes()'.

Comment: @RasmusRosengren Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name

Comment: @PawelMysior already tried. still the same.

Comment: @fahmishah replacing `{{ $quote->authors->name }}` with `{{ $quote->author->name }}` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly what is causing the error, but here are a couple of comments on the code you posted.

I would change your Quotes model as follows:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Quotes extends Model {
    public function author() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Authors');
    }
}
```

I made 2 changes to the Quote model.  First, Laravel 5.2 generally follows [PSR-2 Coding Style Guide](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md), and generally you should to.  So I changed the case of the author() method.  Also, since the relationship is singular I renamed the method with singular plurality.

The plural Authors() relationship method may also be causing problems with Laravel's relationship handling.  Laravel concatenates '_id' to the method name to determine the name of the foreign key field, in your case Laravel will try to fetch the parent Author based on the value in the authors_id field in the Quotes table.  Obviously this field doesn't exist.  Correcting the pluralization of the method name should fix that potential problem.

Lastly, as for the Blade template, I try implementing it like this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
@forelse ($quotes as $quote)   
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ $quote->quotes }} <br>
        <span class="label label-primary">
            @if (quote->author())
                {{ $quote->author()->name }}
            @else
                The author of this quote is missing!!!!
            @endif
        </span>
    </li>
@empty
    <p>No quotes</p>
@endforelse
```

You can also try using a tool like [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to easily see the queries being issued by the ORM. This would let you spot issues with the queries that you can track back to issues in your code.

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering I still cannot find out where the problem is, but I got it working with the code down below

`App/Author.php` (here I changed the file name to Author (singular) from Authors to match the class name)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model {
    // Here I changed the method name to have all lower case
    public function quotes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Quote');
    }
}
```

`App/Quote.php` (File name change is the same as for the Author.php)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Quote extends Model {
    // Method name changed to lower case and singular since it belongs to only ONE other model
    public function author() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }
}
```

`App/Http/Controllers/QuoteController.php` (QuoteController changed from Quote(s)Controller)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Quote;
use App\Author;

// Class name changed accordingly
class QuoteController extends Controller 
{
    public function index() {
        // Changed with('authors') to with('author'), singular
        $quotes = Quote::with('author')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(25);
        // Change the view here
        return view('home', [
            'quotes' => $quotes
        ]);
    }
}
```

`resources/views/home.blade.php`

```
<ul class="list-group">
    @forelse ($quotes as $quote)   
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $quote->quotes }} <br>
            <!-- Changed $quote->authors->name to $quote->author->name -->
            <span class="label label-primary">{{ $quote->author->name }}</span>
        </li>
    @empty
        <p>No quotes</p>
    @endforelse
</ul>
```